# How to skip host alternative name verification

Tags: karate

I have below sample karate script

```
* url 'https://abcd-xxxx.xx.xxx.xxx.xxx/apipath'
* header Content-Type = 'application/json'
* header Accept = 'application/json'
* configure ssl = false
```

Scenario:

Cucumber test steps

With above  test script I am getting below error.

**javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: org.apache.http.conn.ssl.DefaultHostnameVerifier - Certificate for <abcd-xxxx.xx.xxx.xxx.xxx> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: [List of alternative names]
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.DefaultHostnameVerifier.matchDNSName(DefaultHostnameVerifier.java:177)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.DefaultHostnameVerifier.verify(DefaultHostnameVerifier.java:122)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.DefaultHostnameVerifier.verify(DefaultHostnameVerifier.java:99)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.verifyHostname(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:503)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:437)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:384)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:376)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
at com.intuit.karate.http.apache.ApacheHttpClient.makeHttpRequest(ApacheHttpClient.java:313)
at com.intuit.karate.http.apache.ApacheHttpClient.makeHttpRequest(ApacheHttpClient.java:89)
at com.intuit.karate.http.HttpClient.invoke(HttpClient.java:237)
at com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioContext.clientInvoke(ScenarioContext.java:758)
at com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioContext.method(ScenarioContext.java:811)
at com.intuit.karate.StepActions.method(StepActions.java:251)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intuit.karate.core.Engine.executeStep(Engine.java:150)**

I have added the https://abcd-xxxx.xx.xxx.xxx.xxx certificate to the java keystore.  But I am facing above issue . It is known that host name is not present in the cert subject alternative names  sections  which I added in the trust store for the  above host  url.  As of now I don't think I can add the expected alternative in the existing cert .So just checking is there any way to skip the DefaultHostname Verification in karate and I can run the test.

I tried the same insomnia and it is working fine. With SSL = true getting 503 service unavailable error however the  service is running as I can still test from insomnia tool.

Comment: sounds like your server is strict and you need to configure a certificate. please refer other answers: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bkarate%5D+certificate - but I really think `configure ssl = true` should have worked

Answer (score 0):

If `configure ssl = true` does not work, I would work on sorting that out. Else you may need to add a certificate: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bkarate%5D+ssl+certificate

Perhaps this is a gap in Karate, if you can provide a foolproof way to replicate or even better investigate and submit a PR that would be great. Contributing to Karate is easy if you know a little Java.